# Clickable tags / text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm working on an app that includes the names of users with their icons under an image. I'm currently using collection view in order to distribute the names. I'm using this approach since each cell when clicked will be holding the user object. However, I'm having some layout issues when it's used (please check attached image). The spacing is unusual. The desired output is the cells having a certain spacing limit between them and if any cell cannot fit, will be placed on the other line. I tried using the delegate methods for spacing by setting it to 5 however it's not working (the cell's size will be dynamic). Should I subclass and create my own Collection view Layout ? if there is any other approach without using collection views please let me know. Thank you.

[image]